# Can not remove event listener using setTimeout on element using class method

Tags: javascript, class, settimeout, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

So I have this function (App.btnInteractive) that adds or removes mouseover and mouseout event listeners according to the boolean passed into the function call

```
'use strict';

const btnStart = document.querySelector('.btn--start');

class App {
  constructor() {
    btnStart.addEventListener('click', this.start.bind(this));
  }

  btnInteractive(state) {
    console.log(`Check: ${state}`);
    function mouseover() {
      console.log('over');
    }

    function mouseout() {
      console.log('out');
    }
    if (state) {
      btnStart.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseover);
      btnStart.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseout);
    } else {
      btnStart.removeEventListener('mouseover', mouseover);
      btnStart.removeEventListener('mouseout', mouseout);
    }
  }

  start() {
    this.btnInteractive(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.btnInteractive(false);
    }, 2000);
  }
}

const app = new App();
```

That results in console output below after clicking button and moving cursor out of the button and on it after each function call

```
Check: true
out
over
Check: false
out
over
```

So here's my trail of thought:

- Both if and else code blocks execute
- Stripping the code down (resulted in code in question itself)
- Removing click event listener doesn't help
- Removing both click and mouseout also doesn't work

Idea is that after 2 seconds passed the mouseover and mouseout event listeners should be removed.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: You are creating new functions each time you call btnInteractive. So the function you are removing is not the same one you added.

Comment: Move the `mouseover` and `mouseout` functions to top-level, so they're the same function all the time.

Comment: Thanks guys, didn't realize that the functions were not the same ones on add and remove. Moving to top level solves my problem

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert in Javascript, but i think that when you try to remove the event listeners, you need to have the real reference to the function you used before.
When you execute it again inside the setTimeout, it is trying to remove the reference to the new functions "mouseover" and "mouseout" that were created.
Try setting the callbacks for the listeners like that:

```js
if (state) {
    btnStart.onmouseover = mouseover;
    btnStart.onmouseout = mouseout;
} else {
    btnStart.onmouseover = () => {};
    btnStart.onmouseout = () => {};
}
```